# Regex to select specific portion of the rtf source

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to select all data starting from (inclusive) `{\\*\listtable` to `{\\*\listoverridetable{` (exclusive)

Here is a smaple RTF:

```
    {\\rtf1\adeflang1\ansi\\ansicpg1\uc1\adeff3\deff0\stshfdbch3\stshfloch3\stshfhich3\stshfbi3\deflang1\deflangfe1\themelang1\themelangfe0\themelangcs0{\\fonttbl{{\\f0\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\\f0\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}
{\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 020f0502020204030204}Calibri;}{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}
{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\\fhimajor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 020f0302020204030204}Calibri Light;}
{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}
{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\\fhiminor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 020f0502020204030204}Calibri;}
{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset0\fprq2{\\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman;}{\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}
{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}
{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}
{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}
{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}{\\f4\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\\f4\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset2\fprq2Calibri CE;}{\\f4\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset2\fprq2Calibri Cyr;}
{\\f4\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Greek;}{\\f4\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Tur;}{\\f4\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Baltic;}{\\f4\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri (Vietnamese);}
{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}
{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}
{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}{\\flomajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}
{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}
{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}
{\\fdbmajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\\fhimajor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset2\fprq2Calibri Light CE;}{\\fhimajor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset2\fprq2Calibri Light Cyr;}
{\\fhimajor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Light Greek;}{\\fhimajor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Light Tur;}{\\fhimajor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Light Baltic;}
{\\fhimajor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Light (Vietnamese);}{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}
{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}
{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}{\\fbimajor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}
{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}
{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}
{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}{\\flominor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}
{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}
{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}
{\\fdbminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}{\\fhiminor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset2\fprq2Calibri CE;}{\\fhiminor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset2\fprq2Calibri Cyr;}
{\\fhiminor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Greek;}{\\fhiminor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Tur;}{\\fhiminor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri Baltic;}
{\\fhiminor\\f3\fbidi \fswiss\\fcharset1\fprq2Calibri (Vietnamese);}{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman CE;}{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset2\fprq2Times New Roman Cyr;}
{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Greek;}{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Tur;}{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Hebrew);}
{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Arabic);}{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman Baltic;}{\\fbiminor\\f3\fbidi \froman\\fcharset1\fprq2Times New Roman (Vietnamese);}}
{\\colortbl;;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue2;\red0\green2\blue2;\red0\green2\blue0;\red2\green0\blue2;\red2\green0\blue0;\red2\green2\blue0;\red2\green2\blue2;\red0\green0\blue1;\red0\green1\blue1;\red0\green1\blue0;
\red1\green0\blue1;\red1\green0\blue0;\red1\green1\blue0;\red1\green1\blue1;\red1\green1\blue1;}{\\*\defchp \f3\fs2}{\\*\defpap \ql \li0\ri0\sa1\sl2\slmult1
\widctlpar\\wrapdefault\\aspalpha\\aspnum\\faauto\\adjustright\\rin0\lin0\itap0}\noqfpromote {\\stylesheet{{\\ql \li0\ri0\sa1\sl2\slmult1\widctlpar\\wrapdefault\\aspalpha\\aspnum\\faauto\\adjustright\\rin0\lin0\itap0\rtlch\\fcs1\af3\afs2\alang1
\ltrch\\fcs0\f3\fs2\lang1\langfe1\cgrid\\langnp1\langfenp1\snext0\sqformat \spriority0Normal;}{\\*\cs1\additive \ssemihidden \sunhideused \spriority1Default Paragraph Font;}{\\*
\ts1\tsrowd\\trftsWidthB3\trpaddl1\trpaddr1\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tblind0\tblindtype3\tsvertalt\\tsbrdrt\\tsbrdrl\\tsbrdrb\\tsbrdrr\\tsbrdrdgl\\tsbrdrdgr\\tsbrdrh\\tsbrdrv \ql \li0\ri0\sa1\sl2\slmult1
\widctlpar\\wrapdefault\\aspalpha\\aspnum\\faauto\\adjustright\\rin0\lin0\itap0\rtlch\\fcs1\af3\afs2\alang1\ltrch\\fcs0\f3\fs2\lang1\langfe1\cgrid\\langnp1\langfenp1\snext1\ssemihidden \sunhideused Normal Table;}{

\s1\ql \li7\ri0\sa1\sl2\slmult1\widctlpar\\wrapdefault\\aspalpha\\aspnum\\faauto\\adjustright\\rin0\lin7\itap0\contextualspace \rtlch\\fcs1\af3\afs2\alang1\ltrch\\fcs0\f3\fs2\lang1\langfe1\cgrid\\langnp1\langfenp1
\sbasedon0\snext1\sqformat \spriority3\styrsid1List Paragraph;}{\\*\ts1\tsrowd\\trbrdrt\\brdrs\\brdrw1\trbrdrl\\brdrs\\brdrw1\trbrdrb\\brdrs\\brdrw1\trbrdrr\\brdrs\\brdrw1\trbrdrh\\brdrs\\brdrw1\trbrdrv\\brdrs\\brdrw1
\trpaddl1\trpaddr1\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tblind0\tblindtype0\tsvertalt\\tsbrdrt\\tsbrdrl\\tsbrdrb\\tsbrdrr\\tsbrdrdgl\\tsbrdrdgr\\tsbrdrh\\tsbrdrv \ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\\wrapdefault\\aspalpha\\aspnum\\faauto\\adjustright\\rin0\lin0\itap0
\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\afs2\alang1\ltrch\\fcs0\f3\fs2\lang1\langfe1\cgrid\\langnp1\langfenp1\sbasedon1\snext1\spriority3\styrsid1Table Grid;}}{\\*\listtable{{\\list\\listtemplateid6\listhybrid{{\\listlevel\\levelnfc0
\levelnfcn0\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\levelspace3\levelindent0{\\leveltext\\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-3\li7\lin7}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc4\levelnfcn4\leveljc0\leveljcn0
\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\lvltentative\\levelspace3\levelindent0{\\leveltext\\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-3\li1\lin1}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc2\levelnfcn2\leveljc2\leveljcn2\levelfollow0
\levelstartat1\lvltentative\\levelspace3\levelindent0{\\leveltext\\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-1\li2\lin2}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc0\levelnfcn0\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1
\lvltentative\\levelspace3\levelindent0{\\leveltext\\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-3\li2\lin2}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc4\levelnfcn4\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\lvltentative

\levelspace3\levelindent0{\\leveltext\\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-3\li3\lin3}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc2\levelnfcn2\leveljc2\leveljcn2\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\lvltentative\\levelspace3
\levelindent0{\\leveltext\\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-1\li4\lin4}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc0\levelnfcn0\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\lvltentative\\levelspace3\levelindent0
{\\leveltext\\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-3\li5\lin5}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc4\levelnfcn4\leveljc0\leveljcn0\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\lvltentative\\levelspace3\levelindent0{\\leveltext

\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-3\li5\lin5}{\\listlevel\\levelnfc2\levelnfcn2\leveljc2\leveljcn2\levelfollow0\levelstartat1\lvltentative\\levelspace3\levelindent0{\\leveltext

\leveltemplateid6\'0\'0.;}{\\levelnumbers\\'0;}\rtlch\\fcs1\af0\ltrch\\fcs0\fi-1\li6\lin6}{\\listname ;}\listid9}}{\\*\listoverridetable{
```

So far I've wriiten:

```
public String getContent(){           //my method
    String str = null;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("({\\\\\*\\listtable(.*\W)*){\\\\\*\\listoverridetable");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bodyContent);

    if (matcher.find()) {
         str = matcher.group(2);
    }
    return str;
}
```

But it always give me errors like Invalid escape sequence if I try to implement a regex as [this](http://regexr.com/3bhrc). How should I do this in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be very careful with escapes in Java regex. In order to avoid escaping at least some of them, just use a character class `[...]`.

Here is the string that can match the text:

```
String pattern = "(?s)[{]\\\\\\\\[*]\\\\listtable.*?(?=[{]\\\\\\\\[*]\\\\listoverridetable[{])";
```

To match a literal `\`, you need 4 `\` symbols in the regex pattern.

Note the `(?s)` singleline modifier that enables dot to match newline symbols. In your regex, `(.*\\W)*)` is very ineffecient when fetching a newline-containing substring.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/icYkeC)

Comment: But wait I wanted to exclude `{\\*\listoverridetable{`

Comment: ok this worked `Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?s)[{]\\\\\\\\[*]\\\\listtable.*?)[{]\\\\\\\\[*]\\\\listoverridetable[{]");` and then getting `group(1)`

Comment: Just enclose it into a `(?=...)` look-ahead. The regex will check for its presence, but it won't be part of the match. See my updated `pattern`. IDEONE demo is also updated. Or capturing group is also a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\\\*\\listtable(.*\\W)*)\\{\\\\*\\listoverridetable");
```

On some places you have to escape the `\`

Comment: Now its returning me null.

Comment: Of course I also need to escape '{' here. After doing that I get null

Comment: *On some places you have to escape the ``\``* :) - oh so true

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your link, you have not escaped any `\` in java.

You will need to do something like,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("({\\\\\\\\\\*\\\\listtable(.*\\W)*){\\\\\\\\\\*\\\\listoverridetable");
```

Basically, for each `\` you need to write `\\` in java.

Comment: Of course I also need to escape '{' here. After doing that I get null

Comment: @Identity1, no you dont have to escape `{`.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
({\\*\\listtable(.*\W)*)\{\\*\\listoverridetable`

Comment: To match a single literal ``\``, it requires 4 ``\`` in a regex, not 2. ``\\`` will be treated as a regex escape, and ``\\`` after as a ``\`` that is escaped.